# Rename [mongoose] to [mongoosejs] or [mongoose-odm]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Recently I looked about mongoose (the C embedded web-server), but I was a little confused with the Stack Overflow tags:

- [mongoose-web-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose-web-server) is what I am looking for.
- [mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose) is related to http://mongoosejs.com/
- [mongoose-im](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose-im) is related to https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM.

Could it be clearer to rename [mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose) tag [mongoosejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoosejs) or [mongoose-odm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose-odm)?

This seems also confusing for other people, I retag the folowing posts mongoose-web-server instead of mongoose :

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22382639/revisions (asked 2014 Mar 13 at 14:59)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24280464/revisions (asked 2014 Jun 18 at 8:19)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24322675/revisions (asked 2014 Jun 20 at 8:04)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25467125/revisions (asked 2014 Aug 23 at 22:59)

Comment: I added a "retag-request" tag to your post. If that is not what you meant, you can remove it.

Comment: Is there evidence that the "mongoose" tag is being confused?

Comment: Coming back to this post, I see that my comment wasn't very clear.  Is there evidence that it is confused "often"?  I see that you cleaned up about a dozen questions, but they were spread out over several years. Compared to 4,768 current mongoose questions.